# I need to zip all the folders available in a path

Tags: linux

I have a scenario where I need to zip all the folders. Please suggest me few.

I tried using:

```
tar -zcv
```

and `gzip -r` folder name. But it did not work.

Comment: Do you want to do this as a zip file or as a tar gzip file?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I do something like

```
tar cvfz folder.tgz folder
```

Never had any problems with that

`cvfz` stands for **c** reate, **v** erbose, **f** ilename, **z** ip.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Zip

If you truly want to zip a directory tree you can use the `zip` tool like so:

```
$ zip -r archive.zip *
```

#### Example

With a sample directory I'd get the following in the `.zip` file:

```
$ unzip -l archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   1/
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   1/afile
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   2/
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   2/afile
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   3/
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   3/afile
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   4/
        0  10-30-2013 15:26   4/afile
---------                     -------
        0                     8 files
```

#### Using Tar

If you want to accomplish the above using `tar` and `gzip` the resulting `.tar` file afterwards you can use the single command:

```
$ tar zcvf archive.tar.gz *
```

#### Example

With a sample directory I'd get the following in the `.tar.gz` file:

```
$ tar ztvf archive.tar.gz 
drwxrwxr-x saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 1/
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 1/afile
drwxrwxr-x saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 2/
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 2/afile
drwxrwxr-x saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 3/
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 3/afile
drwxrwxr-x saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 4/
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-10-30 15:26 4/afile
```